I can't enable IAM Identity Center service
I opened an AWS account and trying to enable the IAM Identity Center service.
I see the following page when I open IAM Identity Center dashboard.
What is the solution, how can I enable this service?

I didn't enable any service after I create the account. So, they are all in default state which is disabled.


Side-note: IAM Identity Center is for configuring Single Sign-On. This is typically done in large organisations with a directory service (eg Active Directory or LDAP). Mostly, you would be using IAM, which is different to IAM Identity Center.

Go to AWS Organizations > Services and look for AWS IAM Identity Center (AWS Single Sign-On). Click on it, and Enable Trusted Access, then you should be good to go.
